# Help me understand data output from R bayes glm model

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have been given a bunch of csv files which are ouputs of a bayesian glm model run.  I have minimal understanding on machine learning, so apologies beforehand. I'd like to understand what the variables in each column mean, since that is important for my task.

Here is a few first lines of a csv file:

```
  Genotype  Beta    SEBeta  P
pepP1__avg_access_sa_folded__x__hlaP.21__avg_access_sa_folded   0.492653351282333   0.133971382666172   0.000235713099632736
pepP2__avg_access_sa_folded__x__hlaP.21__avg_access_sa_folded   0.374252821916212   0.166440963798524   0.0245403780812961
pepP3__avg_access_sa_folded__x__hlaP.21__avg_access_sa_folded   0.128236595516439   0.144158623951455   0.373706477622523
pepP4__avg_access_sa_folded__x__hlaP.21__avg_access_sa_folded   0.265587277639511   0.135504095415586   0.0499964366890409
pepP5__avg_access_sa_folded__x__hlaP.21__avg_access_sa_folded   -0.0678042568311556 0.147863754510041   0.646550877911669
```

I know what Genotype is, and I'm guessing P is the p value but if anyone knows what the rest are, I'd highly appreciate it.

Comment: beta is probably the beta, i.e. the coefficient of the independent variable. SEbeta will be the standard error of the coefficient.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds logical and clear enough.